# How to observe changes on Live Data when database entries are updated by a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have been trying using Android Room Persistence Library along with Live Data components lately. I observe the list of entries in my Db Table using observers through the View Model to get notified for any additions or updates made to the entries. 
I get my onChanged method called perfectly fine when updates or entries are made from within the Fragment or Activity.
However, I have background tasks scheduled with AlarmManager which make updates to the DB as scheduled by the user using a Broadcast Receiver.
The problem I face is the onChanged method of the Observer isn't called when updates are made to the table from the Broadcast receiver and the App is active.

I expect the onChanged method of the Observer to be called and the listView to be re rendered even when updates are made through the Broadcast Receiver.
Instead, DB updates go through fine but onChanged is not called.
Please Help!

Comment: Provide the code man.

Comment: There's nothing fancy in the code. As I said it works in normal circumstances. I'll do it shortly.

Comment: There probably something *fancy* in the code, otherwise I think it should just work without problem